# I need to bypass Cold Turkey Blocker

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

So the idiot that is me did this:

- Blocked some websites.
- Blocked CMD and Powershell too to prevent myself from changing time.
- Blocked settings.
- Blocked Uninstall.

I honestly don't want to uninstall it. I just want to disable it/change the time so that I bypass the block but now it seems kinda impossible since I blocked CMD and Powershell both.

Any help please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://getcoldturkey.com/support/user-guide/ I haven't read right through it but it would be a pretty useless app if you could just bypass it.

Comment: If it does not run when Windows is in Safe mode, you could try using CMD, PowerShell, etc. there. If not contact their tech support.

Answer (score 1):

The only method known to me is through uninstalling.

It is quite time-consuming and I wouldnt recommend using it unless you really need it. It was last used two years ago (so may be fixed) and may undermine your trust in ColdTurkeyBlocker, you have been warned.

You can only completely remove ColdTurkeyBlocker by using Revo Uninstaller (although this will also remove all your block settings):
https://www.computerbase.de/downloads/systemtools/revo-uninstaller-free/

1. Load up the program and browse to the ColdTurkeyBlocker entry in the
   list.
2. Select uninstall and continue
3. Wait until the Uninstaller is run, it will say sth like "you cannot uninstall during a block". Dismiss that message
4. Select the rightmost option under "Scanning Modes": "Advanced" and press continue
5. Wait for the search to finish.
6. Select all Registry values and delete them. Then continue. (You could try to find if there is a registry value for the current active block and delete that)
7. Select all files and delete them.
8. Restart your computer to finish the removal of ColdTurkeyBlocker.

After the restart you need to reinstall and reconfigure ColdTurkeyBlocker.

Answer (score 1):

i have a link for the direct download (which you hopefully didnt block too)
https://getcoldturkey.com/files/Blocker_Removal_Tool-5cc082fd-d806-40f5-9feb-a3a5a577f67e.exe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).